# Can't find how to extract part of an array using only the index path number. (swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing

I have what I believe to be a very simple question but for some reason, I can't find an answer to it anywhere. Say I have an array:

```
var array = ["Apples","Dogs","Monkeys","Cats","Apples"]
```

With this array, I want to print the data "Monkeys"; how would I print the data "Monkeys" using only the known index number (3)?

I tried this code below, but it only returned the number 3, not the data at index number 3.

```
print(array.index(after: 2))
```

Thanks in advance, hope it's simple.

Comment: Doesnt array[index] not work for you ?

Comment: @MartinR He wants to print "Monkey" and it is on index 2. So it would be `array[2]`

Comment: @dahiya_boy: That is correct. – Anyway, it is all clearly documented, e.g. here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID107 or here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index of an array is sort of like the address to the data. So when you ask to find the index of the array after number 2, you're just asking for the next valid address, not the data inside that address.

If you want to actually find the data after index number 2, you could do this:

```
print(array[2 + 1])
```

or

```
let index = 2

print(array[index + 1])
```

either way, using the brackets tells the code that you actually want to take a look inside that "address".

Lastly, it's important to note that arrays start counting at 0, not 1. So if you're looking to extract "Monkeys" from array, you want to look at array[2] not array[3].

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.